# Redmine upgrade doesn't find mocha dependency

Tags: redmine, rake

I've tried to upgrade my redmine 1.3.0 to 2.0.0 following [these instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade).

I am at step 3/6. In this step, I am trying to run the `rake generate_session_store` command, but I receive the following error:
`Could not find gem 'mocha (= 0.12.3) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

Do you have any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: What version of `mocha` (if any) do you have installed? Run `gem search mocha`.

Comment: I have mocha (0.12.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/Gemfile) Redmine is requiring an exact version of mocha (0.12.3). You have a more recent version. The solution is probably to uninstall your version, and install the version Redmine is looking for:

```
gem uninstall mocha --version 0.12.4
gem install mocha --version 0.12.3
```